# Populate Solr Managed Schema Error

Tags: solr

I am getting the 404 error while trying to populate the schema from "Populate Solr Managed Schema".

```
Job started: Index_Update_Collection=sitecore_core_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException:

Error 404 Not Found
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /solr/sitecore_core_index/schema. Reason: Not Found
```

I am using Sitecore 9.0 update 1 and Solr 6.6.2. Please let me know if I am missing any setting.

Thanks,
Alok...

Comment: Is the schema.xml available on the solr server for the core sitecore_core_index?

Comment: This looks like a Solr issue. Check your Solr admin if the core sitecore_core_index exists or if there are any errors. Also try calling yoursolrserver:port/solr/sitecore_core_index/schema and see what it returns if you have access.

Answer (score 0):

This may indicate that you have an index name specified in a patch config that doesn't exist in Solr. If it's a local install, try:

1. Duplicating an existing core directory (ex. `C:\Solr\solr-x.x.x\server\solr\some_index`)
2. Renaming the dir to the index name you're seeing in the logs
3. Updating the `name` var in `some_index\core.properties` file to match the index name
4. Restarting the Solr service
5. Restarting IIS